# C# File.ReadAllText() throws "wrong" exception when dir path given - why?

Tags: c#, exception

C# method [File.ReadAllText(string filePath)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) does not accept a directory path as argument - it needs a path to a file. I understand that.

But why does it in this case throw an UnauthorizedAccessException instead of an ArgumentException? I think this is not intuitive.

Has anybody an explanation that makes me feel better about this?

Comment: You can always get in touch with Microsoft and thell them they did it wrong.

Comment: @rmjoia This is not a Microsoft issue, they throw each exception for some reason.

Comment: @IpsitGaur yes, my fault, SO is not a humour purpose site, so I shouldn't try to make jokes. my fault.

Answer (score 6):

`File.ReadAllText` throws `UnauthorizedAccessException` in the following cases:

> `path` specified a file that is read-only.
> -or-
> This operation is not supported on the current platform.
> -or-
> `path` specified a directory.
> -or-
> The caller does not have the required permission.

Refer to the [documentation for File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your final exe file needs some privilleges.

Try to run as an admin.